# Perform time consuming tasks before window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I submitted my HTML5 game for a HTML5 game platform for QA review and got the following feedback:

You should not perform time consuming tasks before window.onload but the actual is: DOM is blocked.

I am not sure what this review means. What I am doing now is:

```
$(window).ready(
    ....
);
```

So this is the entry point of all the code. So what is the difference between `$(window).ready` and `$(document).ready()` and `window.onload`. Do they follow a fixed order as to when they are triggered? And what does DOM is blocked mean?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: `$(window).ready` and `$(document).ready` are identical. so is `$("#idonotexist").ready`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### dom ready vs window.load

`$(document).ready(function(){});` is triggered until the HTML is fully parsed and rendered, but before all Assets (images, iframes and so on) are downloaded. `$(window).load` is executed right after all images are downloaded.

This means: `$(document).ready` comes always before `$(window).load`.

#### DOM is blocked

Is quite untechnical and not really the truth. You showcase, that you can manipulate the DOM at "DOM ready" and acutally this is the right event for doing so. What they mean is the following: As long as a script is executing, the browsers main thread is blocked. Which means, that the browser can not render/paint anything in this time and the browser becomes unresponsive.

The idea behind this advice is the following:
If you are executing a script on DOM ready, painting stops and will be delayed after script execution. The user might see some sort of your UI, because at this time the DOM is already rendered and in most cases also the CSS is, but not the images. But if you delay it after window.onload the browser can also render images and iframes, before you block the main thread, which means the user might see a fully rendered site/game sooner, although it isn't technically ready yet.

#### My 2 cents

Wether this is a good approach or not, really depends on a lot of circumstances. If your JS does a lot of UI things, it is bad, because the user won't see the final UI sooner, the user will see it later. If your JS is important for the page to work and the page has some bigger images, it is quite stupid to delay executing script. Consider a mobile user, he might already see the UI to start the game, but your click/tap event isn't yet bound, because there is a big image at the end of your page, which still needs to load?

If you have a performance problem fix it, don't delay it to antoher point, this will also block the main thread. But what you can do: If you have a lot of scripts, you can split those tasks into chunks and execute them at the point, when they are really needed and not initially. For example: You have a Menu and this menu has a hidden sub menu, which needs initially some special dom manipulation. Don't do this at dom ready or on window.load, do it right before it opens for the first time.